# FlatList Data not Appears

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm developing a React Native app.

I'm fetching the `data` from RealmDB and grouping by `listId` that data.

I want to render below data in FlatList but no data appears.

```
 const data = {
  "6": [
    {
      "id": 13,
      "listId": 6,
      "piece": 1,
    },
    {
      "id": 12,
      "listId": 6,
      "piece": 1,
    }
  ],
  "7": [
    {
      "id": 15,
      "listId": 7,
      "piece": 1,      
    },
    {
      "id": 14,
      "listId": 7,
      "piece": 1,       
    }
  ]
}
```

My attempt was:

```
<FlatList
 numColumns={2}
 //keyExtractor={(item) => "key" + item.id}
 data={this.state.data}
 renderItem={({ item }) => (
     <View>
         <Text>{item.piece}</Text>
     </View>
 )}
/>
```

What is the correct way to use above `data` in `FlatList`?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist), `data` must be a plain array, whereas yours is an object. What did you want to display in the `Text` component?

Comment: `{item.piece}`. Is there a way to convert the data to a plain array?

Answer (score 1):

You can flat your data with that approach:

```
const flatten = (data) => Object.values(data).flat();
const data = {
    "6": [
      {
        "id": 13,
        "listId": 6,
        "piece": 1,
      },
      {
        "id": 12,
        "listId": 6,
        "piece": 1,
      }
    ],
    "7": [
      {
        "id": 15,
        "listId": 7,
        "piece": 1,      
      },
      {
        "id": 14,
        "listId": 7,
        "piece": 1,       
      }
    ]
  };

const flatData = flatten(data);
```

And then you can use it as wanted:

```
flatData.map(item => item.piece)
```

Comment: With this approach, I'm losing the grouped data. I'm trying to show in the same group if any block has same `listId`.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can access like this if don't want to change data style.

<FlatList
 numColumns={2}
 data={this.state.data}
 renderItem={({ item }) => (
     <View>
         <Text>{item[0].piece}</Text>
         <Text>{item[1].piece}</Text>
     </View>
 )}
/>
```